# How to connect frontend to json data on heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my first React app on Heroku. I used simple json files for the backend.

Locally, everything runs good: my server is on localhost:8080, and frontend axios calls gets data from it like so:

```js
axios.get(localhost:8080/bench).then( (response) => {
    // my logic here
})
```

My deployment flow is:

- to run a `npm build` and put everything in the build folder into the server end's public folder. Here's the entry-point file:

```js
    const path = require("path");
    const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, "public");
    console.log(publicPath);
    app.use(express.static(publicPath));
    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, "index.html"));
    });
```

- push to build artifacts to Heroku

Doing so,  everything from the frontend part runs good on Heroku.

My concern is that **I can't figure out what axios calls  I should use for the frontend to get the data from the server.** Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

`Localhost` only works on your machine. In your frontend, you'll need to change the axios url to point to the URL of your deployed server like so:

```js
axios.get(`${YOUR_HEROKU_URL}`/bench)
```